# $\sqrt{ 1+a_1x } + \sqrt{ 1+a_2x } + ... + \sqrt{ 1+a_nx } = nx$ has a single positive solution.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $ n>1 $ be an integer, and $ a_1, ..., a_n $ be positive real numbers, then the equation

$\sqrt{ 1+a_1x } + \sqrt{ 1+a_2x } + ... + \sqrt{ 1+a_nx } = nx$

has a single positive solution.

I would like some tips to solve this problem. My only idea was to define two functions one for each expression, but from then on I did not get anything that would help me.

Comment: Denote left-hand side of the equation by $f(x)$, and the right-hand side by $g(x)$. Clearly $f(x)$ is strictly increasing. Show that $f(0) > g(0)$, $f(a) < g(a)$ for $a$ sufficiently big. Is the rest clear?

Comment: @Norbert This lacks an argument to show uniqueness. Hint: Convexity.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand better. it is necessary that the two graphs intersect at a single positive point. For this I need you to $ f(0) > g(0)$ and $f(a) < g(a)$ for $a$ sufficiently large?